# Ngix configuration not work. (Blocking file access)

Tags: nginx

i have a short question. I have this nginx config

```
server {
   root /var/www/html/license/;
   listen 80;
   server_name here is my domain;
   
   location ~ \.txt$ {
       return 403;
   }
   
   location ~ \.php$ {
       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
   }
}
```

my goal is to block access to all .txt files! Why this dont work? all is correct what i made wrong?

Comment: Looks like it should work - when you say it doesn't work, what exactly are you seeing? Does it serve both PHP and text OK, or are you getting some error?

Comment: Sorry. I have no time to answer. It is working. the problem was, i have access may server via a proxy (Clodflrare) which only does https requests and my code only listen for http